# Windows Phone 8 speech recognition exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 app. I am facing problem in speech recognition.
This is my code.

```
SpeechRecognizerUI recoWithUI= new SpeechRecognizerUI();
try
{
    this.recoWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI();

    // Start recognition (load the dictation grammar by default).
    SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

    // Do something with the recognition result.
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0}.", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text));

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Every time I run it, It goes to App.xaml.cs class and points out this problem

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break(); // It focuses on this line.
    }
}
```

Have you any idea how to resolve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i got the problem
Every thing is ok. No problem in the code
The problem is SpeechRecognizerUI class language is en-Us but my phone language was en-UK so what i did is
Just change my Phone language to en-Us and now it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Microphone capability in the WMAppManifest.xml file?

Open WMAppManifest.xml > Capabilities tab > check ID_CAP_MICROPHONE.

Comment: Yes this is enabled. (By the way sorry for my late reply)

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? When it focuses on the Debugger.Break() line, could you hover over the 'e' next to NavigationFailedEventArgs, a box will show.  
Then under Exception get the following values:
Exception > StackTrace, 
Exception > InnerException > Message, 
Exception > InnerException > StackTrace

Comment: Yes i did it
ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e

Exception>stacktrace> (and then it shows some values just like in array form from [0] to [95] and mostly there corresponding values were 0
i.e. 
[0] 3
[1] 0
[2] 0
......
)